# How can I add a new form control to the nested form group?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have this form group:

```
this.form = fb.group({
  'teacher': [''],
  'schools': fb.array([
    fb.group({
      'school_name': [''],
      'school_description': [''],
    })
  }) 
});
```

The question is:

How can I add a new form control (named `school_city`) to a specific *group" of `FormArray` programatically through a function?

Comment: Do you want to add a new `group` to the `schools` *array*? Is this?

Comment: I want to add a control named school_city in the group that is inside the schools array.

Comment: And what's the problem? Why it doesn't work? Isn't it simply put `school_city` as you did for `school_name` and others?

Comment: I want to add it through a function call.

Comment: Hmm, since you're in array you may want to add this control for every group of schools? Also, the question is lack of information. It would be useful if you can you include these comments in your question.

Comment: that could also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55334283/reactive-forms-how-to-add-new-formgroup-or-formarray-into-an-existing-formgroup

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To add some control to every group inside `FormArray`, you can do the following:

```
someFunc() {
  const formArr = this.form.get('schools') as FormArray;

  for (const group of formArr.controls) {
    group.addControl('school_city', this.fb.control(''));
  }
}
```

[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/D1bbefnrVZOyJlAUXFMq?p=info)

**Edit#1**:

As the OP now explains that he wants to add the `control` to a specific group:

You have to pass the index of the group that you want to add the `control`:

```
someFunc(idx: number) {
  const group = this.form.get(`schools.${idx}`) as FormGroup;

  group.addControl('school_city', this.fb.control(''));
}
```

Comment: sorry this dint solve my problem.how can i add the control school_city, only when you click add school city button? Right now every group is added with the control school_city. I actually dont want to be like this.

Comment: @kartik dude, yesterday you confirmed that you want to add it to every control  (you can see what I asked in comments of your post). Anyway, it's too easy to accomplish, see the edit version.

Comment: Also, is there any reason to remove the upvote and accepted answer?

Comment: hi man, actually i want to add formcontrol only for a specific group(based on condition). if you want i can share my code

Comment: ya i dint specify what i want. you assumed that it should be added for every group of array. I thought i can actually  make it with your solution. but i'am unable to do it. i upvoted again. tnx for your effort.

Comment: i added this line   const group: FormGroup = this.form.get(`schools.${idx}`);
.The editor is complaining that type abstractcontrol is not assignable to type formgroup.

Comment: It's just a type cast.. add `as FormGroup` in the end (as I did in my answer).

Comment: Why do we add this as formgroup? Is this not a formarray?

Comment: `schools` is a `FormArray`, `schools` at a specific index is a `FormGroup`.

Comment: may be you can answer the below question,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65429846/loop-through-nested-formgroup-and-change-each-form-control-value-to-null-if-it-h